# Aligning burst pictures

Tags: java, image, image-processing, hdr

I've been playing a bit with some image processing techniques to do HDR pictures and similar. I find it very hard to align pictures taken in bursts... I tried some naïve motion search algorithms, simply based on comparing small samples of pixels (like 16x16) between different pictures that pretty much work like: 
- select one 16x6 block in the first picture, one with high contrast, then blur it, to reduce noise
- compare in a neighbouring radius (also blurred for noise)... (usually using averaged squared difference) 
- select the most similar one.

I tried a few things to improve this, for example using these search alghorithms (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block-matching_algorithm) to speed it up. The results however are not good and when they are they are not robust. Also they keep being computationally very intensive (which precludes usage on a mobile device for example).

I looked into popular research based algorithms like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Kanade_method, but it does not seem very suitable to big movements. If we see burst images taken with todays phones, that have sensors > 12Mpix, it's easy that small movements result in a difference of 50-100 pixels. The Lucas Kanade method seems more suitable for small amounts of motion...

It's a bit frustrating as there seem to be hundreds of apps that do HDR, and they seems to be able to match pictures so easily and reliably in a snap... I've tried to look into OpenCV, but all it offers seems to be the above Lucas Kanade method. Also I've seen projects like https://github.com/almalence/OpenCamera, which do this in pure java easily. Although the code is not easy (one class has 5k lines doing it all). Does anyone have any pointers to reliable resources.

Comment: Can you show code of what you tried so far? Right now this question is too broad

Comment: It'd be hard to post as too many files... sorry

Comment: by the way I don't find this question broad. It is about image alignment techniques and I also referenced the algorithms used so far. The code is not important, it's more about algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [HDR+ paper](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/hdrplusdata.org/en//hdrplus.pdf) by google. It uses a hierarchical algorithm for alignment that is very fast but not robust enough. Afterward it uses a merging algorithm that is robust to alignment failures.

But it may be a little tricky to use it for normal HDR, since it says:

> We capture frames of constant exposure, which makes alignment more robust.

[Here](https://sites.google.com/view/handheld-super-res) is another work that needs sub-pixel accurate alignment. It uses a refined version of the alignment introduced in the HDR+ paper.

[HDR+ code](https://github.com/timothybrooks/hdr-plus)